# STM32WL55JC1 (lora module) is not sending or receiving

Tags: power, stm32, ground, lora

I am using 3 STM32WL55JC1. One for base station and the other two's for sensor node. Everything was fine but then I started UART communication between base station and ESP32. I started coding ESP32 so I unplug the usb cables of stm32wl55jc1 (base station) but GND-GND, RX-TX , TX-RX is still plugged between base station and esp32. After a while, I realize my STM32WL55JC1's lora is not working. I can't send anything and I can't receive anything but microcontroller still working. Can this damage the LoRa module integrated into the STM32WL55JC1? LoRa and STM32 processors are on the same chip. I don't know why it is happening. Any idea ?

Comment: How is your STM32 powered after you unplug USB cable from the STM32?

Comment: @Misaz, I didn't power STM32. I was working with only ESP32 but connections are still on between ESP32 and STM32. Maybe esp32's power broke stm32's lora through gnd or rx-tx pin. I don't know, is this possible ?

Comment: You need to power STM32 somehow. DO you use NUCELO board or do you use your own hardware? In case of own, can you provide schematics?

Comment: @Misaz , I am using STM32WL55JC1 Nucleo board. After I did that mistake, I am powering stm32wl55jc1 chip (broken one) but it's lora not working. It's other functions works like ADC,UART etc. I have 3 Nucleo board, 2 of them working with same code but this one is not working :(

Comment: What mistake did you do? If you burned radio module, then you are out of luck, but it is very hard to break such peripheral while remaining other chip parts working.

Comment: @Misaz, I really don't know what I'm doing. The only thing I did was I didn't plug the stm32 cable while encoding the esp32, but there were esp32 connections with stm32 (GND-GND RX-TX TX-RX)